# A utility type that converts type to tuples of type

Tags: typescript

I want to track changes for a value and sync the differences from it's previous value. So I want to keep the old value and when new value comes, I want to return the new value along with the old value.

```
type VUpdateLike = string | number | 3

class VUpdateHistory<A extends VUpdateLike> {
  oldUpdate: A
  constructor(oldUpdate: A) {
    this.oldUpdate = oldUpdate;
  }

  add(update: A): [A, A] {
    let oldUpdate = this.oldUpdate;
    this.oldUpdate = update;
    return [update, oldUpdate];
  }
}

const hist = new VUpdateHistory<VUpdateLike>(10);

let apair = hist.add(3);

console.log(apair[0] + apair[1]);


const hist2 = new VUpdateHistory<VUpdateLike>('10');

let pair2 = hist.add('3');

console.log(apair[0] + apair[1]);
```

As shown, I want this to work for several types. How can I do this?

I thought I needed below but I don't know how to use it for my problem:

I want to define a type consisting of tuples of same types like this:

```
export type VUpdateLike = [number, number] |
  [string, string] |
  [3, 3]
```

How can I do this without repeating the type, something like this:

```
export type VUpdateLike = Tuple<number | string | 3>
```

Comment: Why do you only return the last old value? Wouldn't it be more appropriate for an update history to either create a new VUpdateHistory for each change you do or track all changes inside the object e.g., an array of previous values? I'm asking because your current example will not be doable with types, since you can't retroactively change the value of the generic "A" without wrapping it with either a function or a new object.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with [distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) like [so](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgrmANhAPAaQHxQLxTVCAD2AgDsATAZygENSQoB%20KAbTQBo8BdKALilIQAbhABOAKHFEwAe1HAooSFABqAVTDkaJADIBLANbRc8JKkrBRe0gHMoAHwFwAtgCMxWKAHovrUi-dRTn83MR5HFgsrW04o6xsuSSA):

```
type Tuple<K> = K extends any ? [K, K] : never

export type VUpdateLike = Tuple<string | number>  // [number, number] | [string, string]
```

But typescript will combine subset types with their superset types, meaning a type like this:

```
export type VUpdateLike = Tuple<string | "test">
```

will resolve into `[string, string]`. Which makes sense since `string | "test"` is as restrictive as just `string`.

**Edit:** Why `K extends any`?

When a conditional type is used together with a generic that is a union (e.g., `number | string | boolean`), the conditional type will iterate over each member of the union and apply the if/else branches individually. For a solution to the `Tuple` problem, we really only need that iterative behavior, which is why I used `K extends any`, a condition that is always true.

**Edit 2:** Version from @jcalz to retain subset types ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.3#code/C4TwDgpgBACghgSwE4B4AqA%20KBeKaoQAewEAdgCYDOUA2gqQGYRJQCqAulAPy2sA0bTgC4opCADdmAKClEwAeyTAooSFABqrMOTgkAMggDW0XPGQoalYEnoBzTgB9apAK4BbAEbNHtAEQALCAAbIPlfHxoARgAmAGZ2DABuKQB6FJVwaE1tXQgDYxxaKxtSWwFiuwjXT2YBaq8kCIDg0N8BZpCwiJjYgR72IA)):

```
type Pair<T> = T extends [infer U] ? [U, U] : never

export type VUpdateLike = Pair<[string] | [number] | ["hello"] | [123]>;
```

This solution utilizes [infer](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#type-inference-in-conditional-types).

Comment: Could you add an explanation for the `K extends any` magic? How come it doesn't allow assigning [number, string] to the variable?

Comment: I've updated the answer explaining it. Should the explanation not be clear enough, tell me so, and I will try to come up with a better description. It's also explained in more detail in the docu I've linked.

Comment: I edited my question to better explain my problem, thanks.

Comment: You might want to link to [the documentation for distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types). Also, if the OP is interested in not repeating their types, you are right that `string | "test"` is doomed from the start, but perhaps you could suggest `[string] | ["test"]` or the like?  [Demo](https://tsplay.dev/mplpzm).  I'd make this my own answer but the fundamentals are already written here so I'll only do so if you don't want to modify this answer with this info.

Comment: @jcalz, I've fixed the mistake of accidentally linking the playground twice instead of the docu and added your answer.